# Compare two dates post_date and post_modified in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, date, compare

I want filter posts which post_modified > post_date (posts modified).

I query on database with

```
"SELECT id, post_title, post_date, post_modified 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND DATE(post_date) <> DATE(post_modified) 
ORDER BY post_modified "
```

the output is right.

But if I use `WP_query` for this:

```
PostQueryExample = new WP_Query(array('orderby' => 'modified', 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_type'=>'post','post_status' => 'publish', 'no_found_rows' => 1, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,                           
        'date_query' => array(
                array(
                    'column' => 'post_date',
                    'compare' => '<',
                ),
                array(
                    'column' => 'post_modified',
                    'compare' => '>',,
                ))))
```

But shows the wrong output, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

SELECT id, post_title, post_date, post_modified
FROM  `wp_posts` 
WHERE  `post_modified` >  `post_date`

Comment: Que is about WordPress and WP_Query arguments should be proposed.